# Why is my data frame created has index for rows not as number (1,2,3,4....), but has index as column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

```
table.q1c =data.frame(Variable.Name = colnames(data1),Data.Type =sapply(data1, class),NA.Count = colSums(is.na(data1)))

table.q1c.new = filter(table.q1c, NA.Count>0)table.q1c.new
```

[image]
Here at the left most column of table.q1c is variable names, not index number for rows.

I have no idea whether is because I did something wrong at the creating data frame step or I need to do anything to solve this problem. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Use `remove_rownames(x)` to remove row names.

Comment: These are the row names of your df. To get rid of the row names you could do `rownames(table.q1c) <- NULL`.

Comment: `data.frame(..., row.names = NULL)` also works. the reason is because the `sapply` and `colSums` returns a _named_ vector which get put into your row names